# Largest known integer $m$ such that Legendre's conjecture is true up to $m$

Tags: prime-numbers

The Legendre's conjecture states that the inteval $(m^2,(m+1)^2)$ contains a
prime $p_n$ for each $m$. I wante to find the largest known integer $m$ such that this conjecture is true up to $m$. Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture#cite_ref-3) assert that this number is $4×10^{18}$ but I see that this is related to the Goldbach conjecture . I very confused about these facts.

Comment: I suspect you want the largest $m$ for which it is _known_ that this conjecture holds up to $m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P$ be the largest known prime and $m=\lfloor\sqrt P\rfloor$. Then 
$$
m^2<P<(m+1)^2.
$$
Since $P$ is the largest known prime, $m$ is the largest integer known for which Legendre's conjecture holds.

A different question would be to ask for the largest integer $m$ such that the conjecture holds for all smaller integers.